# Google Analytics Reporting API V4 batchGet quota

Tags: google-analytics-api

in the Reporting API V4 you can do a batchGet and send up to 5 requests at once.
How does this relate to the quota ? Does it count as one request even if i put multiple ones in the request ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Limits and quotas

It depends on what [limits and quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#analytics_reporting_api_v4) you are talking about. Note you can always check the API specific quotas in the [Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/quotas).

#### Quota group for the Analytics Reporting API V4:

Each `batchGet` requests counts as one request against these quotas:

- Requests per day per project: 50,000
- Requests per 100 seconds per project: 2,000
- Requests per 100 seconds per user per project: 100.

Meaning you can put up to 5 requests into each `batchGet` for a total of 250,000 request per day.

#### General reporting quotas

There are some quotas [general reporting quotas](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas#reporting_apis), in which each individual request within a `batchGet` acts individually against your quota.

- 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day.
- 10 concurrent requests per view (profile).

This means if you put 5 requests in a single `batchGet` and make 2 `batchGet` requests at the same time you will be at the 10 concurrent requests per view limit, and if you continue to put 5 requests in each `batchGet` request throughout the day you will only be able to make 2,000 `batchGet` requests against a single view.

### Analytics Reporting API V4 `batchGet` considerations

A note about the [ReportRequest](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.view_id) objects within a `batchGet` method.

Every `ReportRequest` within a `batchGet` method must contain the same:

- [`viewId`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.view_id)
- [`dateRanges`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.date_ranges)
- [`samplingLevel`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.sampling_level)
- [`segments`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.segments)
- [`cohortGroup`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#ReportRequest.FIELDS.cohort_group)